# Does it affect map loading speed/performance? addAnnotation vs. addAnnotations

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkmapview

I know that both of these two functions work with multiple points on my map view - I can either loop through a set of pins and do an `addAnnotation:pin` on each one, or I can set up an array and use the `addAnnotations:arrayOfPins` method...

But I'm wondering, since I will often have the program add a new annotation, and sometimes sets of a few, would it be okay to just use `addAnnotation:pin` in a function, and loop through a set of, say, 30 or 40 pins, then keep using that function for adding new pins elsewhere, rather than have that function, plus a function to load in an array of pins?

Basically, is looping through a bunch of `addAnnotation` calls for *everything* noticably slower and/or dumber than using `addAnnotation` for single annotations, and `addAnnotations` for sets of annotations?

It's not a huge issue, I just didn't know if using the array function was any better in any way?

Comment: I have no idea which one is faster but I wouldn't be surprised if `addAnnotations` just looped through the array and called `addAnnotation`... :)

Comment: Without knowing the internals, can't say for sure, but I agree with @donkim - I would bet damn good money that that array will be iterated over again.

Comment: Heh, sounds like the way I would do it!

Comment: It's times like this it would be great if iOS were an open-source project. When I have questions like this about Drupal, for instance, I can just pop into the main function/class and see exactly what's going on!

Comment: For large sets of annotations I would expect addAnnotations to be slightly faster. The reason is that the maps' container can then allocate space in one go and then add all the new objects in. But, if they prepare space in batches anyway, it won't make any difference. But knowing how many they need to add in advance gives them the potential to make it faster at least :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my own testing, with a small set of some 200 pins, it doesn't look like either is faster. I'm going to simply use one function that adds one annotation at a time, and loop through adding annotations via another function, since that will make my code a little simpler.

But either way is probably just as easy.

Comment: Also, as an aside, it's kinda fun to watch all 200 pins animate as they drop onto the map :-)